# How move Firefox bookmarks from Windows to Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, windows, firefox, password, bookmarks

How can I move Firefox bookmarks from Windows to Ubuntu? I have Windows XP on one machine (which is very old and runs Firefox 8) and have Ubuntu 11.10 on another. I want to copy Firefox bookmarks to the Ubuntu machine.

Comment: Since you've accepted an answer here, you might want to edit your question to remove the part about stored passwords...and then [ask a separate question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) about how to move your stored passwords.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Backup and restoring

#### Manual backup

1. At the top of the Firefox window, click the Bookmarks menu and select Show All Bookmarks to open the Library window.
2. In the Library window, click the Import and Backup button and then select Backup....
3. In the Bookmarks backup filename window that opens, choose a location to save the file, which is named bookmarks-"date".json by default. The desktop is usually a good spot, but any place that is easy to remember will work.
4. Save the bookmarks json file. The Bookmarks backup filename window will close and you can close the Library window.

#### Restoring from backups

*Caution: Restoring bookmarks from a backup will overwrite your current set of bookmarks with the ones in the backup file.*

1. At the top of the Firefox window, click the Bookmarks menu and select Show All Bookmarks to open the Library window.
2. In the Library window, click the Import and Backup button and then select Restore.
3. Select the backup from which you want to restore:

   1. The dated entries are automatic backups.
   2. Choose File... lets you restore from a manual backup (see above).
4. After choosing a backup, your bookmarks from that file will be restored. Close the Library window.

### Moving bookmarks to another computer

#### Using Firefox Sync

You can use Firefox Sync to move your bookmarks from one computer to another.
*Note: Firefox Sync continuously updates itself as you change bookmarks, so it does not provide a true backup service, nor is it intended to be used as one.*

Firefox Sync is the best way to keep your bookmarks (and other profile data) synchronized between all of the computers you use. See What is Firefox Sync? for more information and How to sync Firefox settings between computers for instructions on setting it up.
Using a bookmark backup file

#### Using a bookmark backup file

You can also use a bookmark backup file from one computer and restore it on another computer. This is useful if you can't Sync the two computers, for some reason.

The bookmark backup file can either be a manual backup (see above) or one of the automatic dated backups located inside the Firefox profile folder bookmarkbackups folder. Place the bookmark backup file on your transfer media (e.g. a Flash drive) and copy it to the desktop (or any location) of the other computer. You can then restore the backup from the Firefox Library window, using the Choose File... option, as described in the Restoring from backups section above.

*Source: Derived [from this article](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/back-up-bookmarks-or-move-them-to-another-computer) ("Back up your bookmarks or move them to another computer") by [AliceWyman](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/user/11), [Chris_Ilias](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/user/13), [Verdi](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/user/160087), [scoobidiver](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/user/209080), [rnewman@mozilla.com](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/user/337751), [mluna](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/user/463178), and [greasemonkey](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/user/499725).*

Answer (score 1):

In the Bookmarks tab 'Show all bookmarks' (where you can add/delete/edit bookmarks) there's a tab 'Import and backup'. The name says it self: you can import/export and backup/restore your bookmarks to transfer to a different system/browser. It's easy...

Comment: More details for this technique, and alternate techniques, [can be found here](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/back-up-bookmarks-or-move-them-to-another-computer).

Comment: ok good how to copy passwords

Answer (score 1):

go to -> tools -> set up sync...

this will allow you to sync all your passwords, bookmarks, histories if you wish.

One you've set up your sync type,

about:home in the url bar on your primary computer

and press the sync button at the bottom of the page

this will allow you to enter the code from your new computer and...

voila